# What does the |= operator do in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, language-features

Browsing the code sample from [C# 4.0 in a nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ch03.aspx)
I came across some interesting operators involving enums

```
[Flags]
public enum BorderSides { Left=1, Right=2, Top=4, Bottom=8 }

...
BorderSides leftRight = BorderSides.Left | BorderSides.Right;
...

BorderSides s = BorderSides.Left;
s |= BorderSides.Right;
...

s ^= BorderSides.Right;
```

Where is this documented somewhere else?

**UPDATE**

Found a [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/51e5f20b-7da4-4dd2-ab44-2ddb5802fa88/) relating to this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`|=` is a bitwise-or assignment.

This statement:

```
BorderSides s = BorderSides.Left;
s |= BorderSides.Right;
```

is the same as

```
BorderSides s = BorderSides.Left;
s = s | BorderSides.Right;
```

This is typically used in enumerations as flags to be able to store multiple values in a single value, such as a 32-bit integer (the default size of an `enum` in C#).

It is similar to the `+=` operator, but instead of doing addition you are doing a bitwise-or.

Answer (score 3):

For your reference - [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) and [|=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bitwise OR operator, not to be confused with logical or (dealing with bools).

Wikipedia has a great article on this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

Comment: Why not confused? It works for bools as well. What it does depends of arguments, anyway in both cases a |= b is equvalent of a = a | b.